# How do I set a list choice to predefined days of the week, and 1 choice to a user input date?

Tags: applescript

Here is what I have so far. I originally created it without a list but I am limited to only 2 creation dates.

I would like to set these 4 list choices:

"Today" to Today
"Tomorrow" to Tomorrow
"This coming Monday" would depend on the current day of the week. If the current day of the week is Monday add 7 days, if Tuesday add 6 days, Wednesday add 5 days, Thurs. add 4 days, and Friday add 3 (like you already see in the script).
"Other" might be trickier, I would like the user to enter the date manually.

```
set theDateChoices to {"Tomorrow", "Today", "This coming Monday", "Other"}
set theDatePick to choose from list theDateChoices with prompt "Select the folder creation date:" default items {"Tomorrow"}
# theDatePick

# set Tomorrow to 
# set Today to
# set This coming Monday to
# set Other to input date manually

set currentDay to weekday of (get current date)
if currentDay = Friday then
    set n to 3
    
else
    
    set n to 1
end if
set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to ((current date) + n * days)
--set m to m + 1

set theYearLong to y as string
set theYearShort to shorten(y)


set theMonthNumberZero to pad((m as integer) as string)
set theMonthNumber to ((m as integer) as string)
set theMonthLong to m as string
set theMonthShort to shorten(m)


set theDayNumberZero to pad((d as integer) as string)
set theDayNumber to ((d as integer) as string)



on pad(thisNumber)
    if length of thisNumber = 1 then
        return "0" & thisNumber
    else
        return thisNumber
    end if
end pad


on shorten(thisItem)
    
    if class of thisItem is integer then
        return characters 3 thru -1 of (thisItem as text) as string
    else
        return characters 1 thru 3 of (thisItem as text) as string
    end if
end shorten

#set theFolderNameDate to theYearLong & "_" & theMonthNumberZero & "_" & theDayNumberZero as text
#set theDuplicatedFolderName to theFolderNameDate

# log theFolderNameDate
# log theDuplicatedFolderName

set theFileNameDate to theYearLong & "_" & theMonthNumberZero & "_" & theDayNumberZero as text
```

Comment: What is going to be the valid format the user can enter for **Other**?  What do you intend to do with whatever choice was made from the _list_? Note that this probably can be setup as a _handler_ to be called from whichever in the `if theDatePicked ...` _block_ is validated, assuming the primary _action_ to be taken is the same, just differing _dates_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some missing information in your question and as such here is an example of how I'd write and structure the *code*.

When you file in the missing pieces, I'll update the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

The `return ...` statements in the `if theDatePicked ...` *block* are just there as *placeholders*, and were placed there for debugging to see what *value* they held.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property dateObjectToday : (current date)
property dateObjectTomorrow : (current date) + 1 * days
property dateObjectNextMonday : missing value
property currentWeekday : weekday of dateObjectToday
property otherDate : missing value
property theDateChoicesList : {"Today", "Tomorrow", "Next Monday", "Other"}

set theDatePicked to ¬
    choose from list theDateChoicesList with prompt ¬
        "Select the folder creation date:" default items {"Tomorrow"}

if theDatePicked is {"Today"} then
    
    --  # Do Today something.
    
    return dateObjectToday
    
else if theDatePicked is {"Tomorrow"} then
    
    --  # Do Tomorrow something.
    
    return dateObjectTomorrow
    
else if theDatePicked is {"Next Monday"} then
    
    set dateObjectNextMonday ¬
        to my returnNextMondayAsDateObject()
    
    --  # Do Next Monday something.
    
    return dateObjectNextMonday
    
else if theDatePicked is {"Other"} then
    
    set msg to "Type in the date of your choice:"
    set otherDate to text returned of ¬
        (display dialog msg default answer ¬
            "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2)
    
    --  # Do Other something.
    
    return otherDate
    
end if


--  ## Handlers ##

to returnNextMondayAsDateObject()
    if currentWeekday = Monday then
        set n to 7
    else if currentWeekday = Tuesday then
        set n to 6
    else if currentWeekday = Wednesday then
        set n to 5
    else if currentWeekday = Thursday then
        set n to 4
    else if currentWeekday = Friday then
        set n to 3
    else if currentWeekday = Saturday then
        set n to 2
    else if currentWeekday = Sunday then
        set n to 1
    end if
    return dateObjectToday + n * days
end returnNextMondayAsDateObject
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the script with the date format. Basically, I am creating dated folders and files for example "2021_09_07". Thx